# If $\omega=x dy - y dx$ is a $1$-form, how do I compute $d\omega$?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, differential-forms

> If $\omega=x dy - y dx$ is a $1$-form, how do I compute $d\omega$?

I am having trouble understanding the definition of $1$-form and computing $d\omega$.

I know a $1$-form is an expression of the form $F(x,y)dx+G(x,y)dy$.

Answer (score 3):

> I know a $1$-form is an expression of the form $F(x,y)dx+G(x,y)dy$.

Good.  You may also know that the differential of a function (zero-form) is a one-form:
$$
    dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \,dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\,dy
$$
and that you can differentiate a basic one-form like so:
$$
    d(F\,dx) = dF \wedge dx
$$
If you combine the previous two equations, and the two similar ones for $d(G\,dy)$, **and** the fact that the wedge product is skew-symmetric, you have all you need.

Answer (score 0):

If $\omega=P dx+Q dy$, use the identity $\displaystyle d\omega= \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) \ dxdy$.

So, if $\omega=x dy - y dx$, then we have $$d\omega=2 \ dxdy.$$